# Rerun InputBox when there is a wrong variable type input error

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox

My goal is to rerun the InputBox when it crashes and give the user another chance to give the right type of input. (Like it crashes, you get a msgbox where it says "sorry your entry is not available, please retry", and it would jump back to the InputBox.)

```
Test1:
qm = InputBox("Wie viele Quadrat Meter hat die Wohnung?" & vbLf & "Bitte geben sie die QM Zahl an.", Angabe)
If IsError(qm) Then GoTo Test1
```

`qm` is defined as an `Integer`, =0, and below there is a `Select Case` mutilple alternative which changes `qm` to a number from 1-600.

When I type in text like "Hey guys", Excel gives me error 13 (Runtime error 13': type mismatch).

Comment: You can use the `Application.InputBox` version of **VBA**, see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's why in VBA you can use the `Application.InputBox` with a 4th parameter `Type`. If you use `Type:=1` then only Numeric values are allowd.

**Code**:

```
Dim qm As Integer

qm = Application.InputBox("Wie viele Quadrat Meter hat die Wohnung?" _
            & vbLf & "Bitte geben sie die QM Zahl an.", "Angabe", Type:=1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for editing my question so that it is more readable. The Allpication.Inputbox worked great and I will try to take your editing as an example for future posts and answers.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like below

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim qm As String
    qm = 0
Test1:
    qm = InputBox("Enter value")
    If Not IsNumeric(qm) Then GoTo Test1
End Sub
```

Declare `qm` as `String` and check whether its numeric or not. Then you'll have to convert `String` into `Integer` using `CInt()`.

Comment: Thank you. The IsNumeric() solution was gives for my task as a tip but I am glad you showed me how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `If IsError(qm) Then GoTo Test1` with `On Error GoTo Test1`, and `On Error GoTo 0` to reset the error handler.

Details can see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/on-error-statement

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to solve this. I would suggest to define a variable as `variant` (can hold any datatype) and check if it is numeric:

```
dim answer as variant, qm as integer
do while true
    answer = InputBox(...)
    if isNumeric(answer) then
        qm = cInt(answer)
        exit do
    endif
loop
```

Comment: Man this is, for me, a smart solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can set an event to validate de content of the TextBox every time it changes.  I checked that is a number, but you can validate any other condition you need.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
  validator = IsNumeric(TextBox1.Value)
  If validator = False Then
    MsgBox "WARNING! You must enter a number!"
    TextBox1.BackColor = &HFF8&
  End If
End Sub
```